# how to use na_rm with rpy2 rlf.tapply function

Tags: r, python-3.x, na, rpy2

I'm using rpy2 to run a piece of R code in Python and trying to use the tapply functionality from R as follows:

```
import rpy2.rlike.functional as rlf
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
minT = rlf.tapply(all_data['T'], list(date), min, na_rm=True)
```

However, I get this error:
TypeError: tapply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'na_rm'

In the R code it is na.rm, and I know I need to switch "." to "_" in rpy2. How do I solve this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is is a `R` function, `True` would be `TRUE` and instead of `na_rm`, it would be `na.rm`

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as rlf
rlf.r('tapply(all_data$T, all_data$date,  FUN = min, na.rm=TRUE)')
```

---

With a reproducible example

```
>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
>>> import rpy2.robjects as rlf
>>> rlf.r('data(iris)')
>>> rlf.r('out <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species, FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE)')
>>> rlf.r('out')
#R object with classes: ('array',) mapped to:
#[2.300000, 2.000000, 2.200000]
```

Comment: I tried that first, but it gives: minT = rlf.tapply(all_data['T'], list(date), min, na.rm=TRUE)
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression, where the ^ points to the space just before the na.rm

Comment: Thank you. I was able to reproduce your example but it does not work for my data because I'm reading in my R dataframe into a pandas dataframe and therefore applying the R functions to python objects. But I will keep this in mind for using simpler R objects in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually calling the min function from python. So the rlf.tapply you are using is actually executing R like functions (e.g tapply..) and returning them in a python object

We can try:

```
import rpy2.rlike.functional as rlf 
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
import math    
minT = rlf.tapply([float('nan'),1,2,3],[0]*2+[1]*2,min)
# returns [(0, nan), (1, 2)]

minT = rlf.tapply([float('nan'),1,2,3],[0]*2+[1]*2,
lambda x:min([i for i in x if not math.isnan(i)]))
#returns [(0, 1), (1, 2)]
```

You can see this clearly when you use a function that is in R but not in python:

```
rlf.tapply([0,1,2,3],[0]*2+[1]*2,median) 
# returns error
```